# CMS without a template?

Tags: php, content-management-system

Is there a CMS that can manage content on a site without having to implement a template?

I've already designed a site with XHTML and CSS, so don't need a template, but do need active content management in static places, such as articles on the homepage and on a couple of other pages.

Preferably open-source all the way, and tableless layout.

Comment: Rolling back diamond moderator edits is a dangerous game.  You shouldn't play it, especially when the edit is [good](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/135887).

Comment: Edit seemed pointless to me. "Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen WordPress's backend used as a CMS without a front end template. They used WordPress to write, organize, and otherwise manage content, but used their existing site plus a few database queries to pull in the content from WP.

It may be easier to just create a basic WordPress template from your existing site's design. It takes about 10 minutes when you've done it a lot, or a few hours for a newbie.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to add the active content parts to your designed site. That means you are creating a template.

A solution could be wordpress. It allows to add small dynamic parts to your site and has a relatively low learning curve. It's open source too.

Answer (score 0):

Try Cute News.

http://cutephp.com/

It will allow you to add new articles, and you can implement it into your current design easy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Serene CMS. It allows you to use a powerful WYSIWYG editor and insert that content wherever you want with one line of code.

http://demo.serenecms.com